# Is there a way to get a Facebook Page access token without having it tied to a particular user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-page, facebook-access-token

I have been generating a token from the Facebook developer tools in our app (under Messenger -> Settings -> Token Generation). But the never expiring token is then directly tied to my account. I work for a large company and we have been working on a Facebook Message Bot and it’s going to be released soon but I don’t want that token to be directly tied to my account. People switch projects and companies all the time and I don’t want my personal account be tied to this project.
If my research is correct, then that token could be invalidated by 3 different things (maybe more?):

- Change in my Facebook account password
- I lose admin access for the Facebook page
- I delete or de-authorize our Facebook App

I don’t want me privately resetting my Facebook password to create an outage at work.
I work in the engineering department and the marketing department owns Facebook Page. I worry that someday someone is going to go to the settings, see a name they don’t recognize in the admins (my name) and then remove me from the list, creating an outage.
In the process of testing other facebook related project at work I sometimes need to de-authorize the app so I can test the authorization flow.

Today I tried to create just a generic user account that I could grant permissions to and that could stay with the team as different developers join and leave the team. However, it has to be linked to a mobile phone to be valid. The moment I added my cell number it removed that cell number from my private account. I need my private account to have a cell number because I have 2 step authentication required if you are an admin in our app. I can’t use my cell for both account. Plus I don’t want my cell to be connected to a project I might switch off of eventually.

Before I pursue getting a cell phone just for the sake of creating a separate account, is there a way to get a page access token that is not connected to a user account?

Anyone else having this problem? I feel like anyone who is creating a Facebook bot must be running into this. Is there a magical solution that I am just not seeing?

Comment: You are not allowed to have more than one Facebook account. And no there is no way to create a page access token without a user. That is by design. If the user loses access to the page they should not be able to access it anymore.